# Making a popup window/toastbox when WPF application starts

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm very new to WPF, I've been working in WinForms a bit before now, in Visual Studio. I'm making an application for my company that is to be designed for use by the end user.

I need to find out what object I need as a splash screen type thing, but I plan on having a button or something in there, so a popup window might work? I'm not sure.

What I do really need to know is how to initiate an object like a popup window on startup of the application, thanks:)

Comment: I don't think the question is clear enough. Do you mean a splash screen or just a window with a textbox, or something else? If there's no example code, maybe a screenshot of a window similar to the one you want might help.

Comment: sounds to me that you want to keep receiving payment from your company, but offload actual work to someone else

Comment: @MichalDiviš yeah something like a splash screen, i need to experiment though. sorry about my non-clarity, im looking for what object i might need for a splash screen (maybe with buttons and/or interactive areas for small purposes), and how i can initiate this object on startup of the software, thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ASh im not, im very new and actually not a coder. my boss has asked me to work on this as an ongoing background project. all i want to know is what object im looking for and how i can initiate that object on startup of the application (as you can read in my other reply to the more helpful individual.) sorry im not super knowledgeable, but i dont know where else to look other than a community. idk what else youd like me to do when stuck?

Comment: @MichalDiviš ive edited my question, i hope thats clearer :)

Comment: "im very new and actually not a coder" - this is not a valid excuse to ignore site rules. "my boss has asked me to work on this. idk what else youd like me to do when stuck?" - talk to your boss. if you need advice about that - ask for help at https://workplace.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Try a web search for "wpf splash screen", e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268968/wpf-splash-screen-windows

Comment: Sounds like you need a basic splash screen, so as @StefanWuebbe said, just google "WPF splash screen"...

Comment: @ASh i dont know what rules im ignoring mate, im asking for help on a particular issue i have, just trying to get to grips with coding. my boss is not a programmer either, we are simply trying something new. i dont understand your issue with my post at all

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite difficult to understand you question, however if you want a custom Splash screen, it can easily be done by adding the code to the `App.xaml.cs` by overriding `OnStartup` method. Hope that will help you.

Example:

```cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
 //Create a windows instance - Ideally you should create a custom window xaml and create instance of it
 var splashscreenwindows = new Window();
 //This will ensure that the SplashWindows will be shown above all other windows
 splashscreenwindows.Topmost = true;
 //Display a windows
 splashscreenwindows.Show();
 //Set a timer. This is needed for cases, when the machine is too fast, in order to insure that splashscreen will be shown
 Thread.Sleep(1000);
 //Do you initializing work here
                
 //Close the Splashscreen
 splashscreenwindows.Close();
    
 //Continue with the default behavior
 base.OnStartup(e);
}
```